# Facebook API tag publish pages by page ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook API I need to know how to tag published pages while posting. Here in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed) I found a page using `@[page-id]` in the message key but I am not able to tag the pages. Please help me how to do that using my app.

```
$params = array(
    "access_token" => $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'], 
    //"message" => $_SESSION['address']." Test message",
    "message" => "Test message @[19292868552] tag",
    "link" => $site,
    "picture" => $_SESSION['file_name'], 
    "name" => "WeAreVapour",
    "description" => "Vapor Technology Association"
);

try {
    $ret = $fb->post('/me/feed', $params);                            
    echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Have you paid attention to what it says in the description?

Comment: it will not work in description. @CBroe

Comment: I meant, have you paid attention to the explanation of how tagging pages works, and what restrictions are placed on it, in the documentation section that _describes_ the message field.

Comment: Yes i did and i used graph explorer where i can generate the token everytime new permissions are applied.

Comment: I have ised this also. This only prints 'Want to know how to do it?' @[234536506704295:0:Want to know how to do it?]. If anybody have any idea please explain where i am doing wrong.